# How to add text to facceted plot while colouring the points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I am trying to add text to facetted plot which I can do with

```
datasets_text <- data.frame(cyl = unique(mtcars$cyl))
datasets_text$label <- c('text1','text2','text3')

mtcars <- head(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp,drat))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl)+
  geom_text(size    = 2,
          data    = datasets_text,
          mapping = aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = label),
          hjust   = 1.05,
          vjust   = 1.5)
```

[image]

And I also want to colour the points which I can do with

```
mtcars <- head(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp,drat, colour=gear))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl)+
```

[image]

However, when I combine the two

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp,drat, colour=gear))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl)+
  geom_text(size    = 2,
          data    = datasets_text,
          mapping = aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = label),
          hjust   = 1.05,
          vjust   = 1.5)
```

I get `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'gear' not found`. How can I add text to the facets while also coloring the points?

Comment: try adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the `geom_text` call. Also, please consider posting `datasets_text`, so that SO users may try this on their own machine.

Comment: @bouncyball ah yes meant to include that but forgot, added it now. The inherit.aes=FALSE works, thanks!

Comment: ok. I'll add it as an answer

Comment: Or move `aes(colour = gear)` to `geom_point`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the call to `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp,drat, colour=gear))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~cyl)+
    geom_text(size    = 2,
              data    = datasets_text,
              mapping = aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = label),
              hjust   = 1.05,
              vjust   = 1.5, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

From [the `geom_text` help file](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html) regarding `inherit.aes`:

> If FALSE, overrides the default aesthetics, rather than combining with
>   them. This is most useful for helper functions that define both data
>   and aesthetics and shouldn't inherit behaviour from the default plot
>   specification